# I can't test any project in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: html, firefox, testing, proxy, aptana

When I try to test my project, firefox opens up and, instead of showing the page, the download dialog pops up. 
The page is standard XHTML (didn't even work with the template).

I'm behind a proxy, but I tried with 127.0.0.1 and localhost as exceptions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems the problem was the *extension* of the page. I was using an .xhtml page. When I changed to XHTML with an .html extension, it worked.